# Is it possible to kill "yourself" without dying?

Tags: candy-box-2

In the world you teleport to when you drink the X potion, is it possible to kill "yourself" without dying?

Put the answer under a spoiler.

Comment: This does not make sense you have to die if you want to kill your self

Comment: I figured it out it might be possible if you have pink enchanted gloves.